# How to mask a form input field when it is not selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make a form where the credit card field is masked when not selected. So the user would put in their credit card info (numbers visible), but when they click to a different input field the credit card number would turn into something like this - '************'.
If they are to click back on the CC field, the numbers would reappear.
Not sure how to go about doing this...?

I just have basic form CSS right now, nothing special

```
<form><label>*Credit Card Number</label><input required type="text" name="AccountNumber" id="AccountNumber" value="" maxlength="19"/></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
$('#AccountNumber').on("focus", function() {
    $(this).attr('type', 'text');
});
$('#AccountNumber').on("blur", function() {
    $(this).attr('type', 'password');
});

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like sort of a hacky way to do it, but it's definitely the simplest and quickest

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur', function(){this.type = "password"})

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('focus', function(){this.type = "text"})
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Although I'm not all that sure of why you'd want to obscure it in the first place if it just comes back when you click into the field again, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! some company policy.... i dont know man.

Comment: if i want to make this field different than the others, do i just change the 'this.type = "text"' to something else custom?

Comment: how do i make this only occue to a specific label and not others?

Comment: It'll need to still be `text`, but you can give it an ID or a class